# Errors when using the CardContent component in Material UI beta

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am attempting to migrate from the previous version of Material UI to the new beta, however this error is driving me mad.

To put it simply, this works fine with no errors:

```
const Setup = () => {
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader title="Let's get set up." />
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Setup;
```

But this does not:

```
const Setup = () => {

  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader title="Let's get set up." />
        <CardContent>
        </CardContent>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Setup;
```

Here are the errors produced:
[image: Screenshot of errors]

Comment: what version do you use?

Comment: ``</div>http://i.imgur.com/nXJXl0U.png`` What does this mean?

Comment: @Sagivb.g v1.0.0-beta.25

Comment: @DevangNaghera Apologies, that was just an error pasting. I've edited the question

Comment: Does CardContent component really exists from wherever you importing it?

Comment: @NatKarmios strange indeed, it works in their [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5p7724mwo) with same version

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *Devang Naghera* for pointing this out.

I noticed that `CardContent` is `undefined`, even though I import it at the top of my file with

```
import Card, { CardHeader, CardContent } from 'material-ui/Card';
```

A workaround seems to be to change my imports to

```
import Card, { CardHeader } from 'material-ui/Card';
import CardContent from 'material-ui/Card/CardContent';
```

The code works now.

**Edit:**

It turns out this issue was being caused by some files left over from an older version of MUI. I deleted `node-modules` and redownloaded dependencies, which fixed the issue for me.